# How to deal with 'check my answer'/'see my answer' comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

The following is an excerpt from comments to a question, which will go un-linked (yes, we can all find the comment thread easily enough from my own activity, but doing so serves no purpose and this isn't intended to be censorious or punitive):

> @OP see my answer below... –  UserOne
>
> @OP Check my answer :) –  UserTwo
>
> Can we stop the '(check|see) my answer' comments? The OP is notified, via the Global Inbox (or whatever it's called these days), whenever an answer, or a comment is posted. Incidentally, both comments flagged as 'obsolete.' –  Me
>
> ...
>
> @Me He explicitly asked, how can he access the id after setting it to the image, I had answered the same hece I told him to refer the answer, that's all. –  UserOne
>
> @UserOne: because you didn't think he'd be notified of your answer appearing? The OP is notified of new answers. The OP is also notified of edits to existing answers. So, your comment adds no value or use, and serves only to litter the comment-space with noise. –  Me

I flagged one of these comments (from UserOne, I think) as simply 'obsolete' and the other as 'Other' (with the explanation: "Effectively obsolete, since the OP is notified of answers anyway; feels like a plea for attention and cries of 'FIRST!!' from the bad old days of the net. The previous comment is also flagged.")

Now, my own viewpoint is - probably - obvious at this point, as is my rationale:

The user asking the question is notified of all comments, all new answers and all edits to answers to his or her question; therefore I see absolutely no point in also adding a comment to the question asking that person to go and check the answer. Presumably, and certainly in my own experience, on notification of an answer (or edit to that answer) the OP will check it to see if it works.

So, my question: should these comments be considered as 'obsolete,' or am I missing an inherent value? As noted by the response to myself, from UserOne there is at least one contrasting view.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In one of the comments you cite, you wrote (**emphasis** mine):

> @UserOne: because you didn't think he'd be notified of your answer appearing? The OP is notified of new answers. **The OP is also notified of edits to existing answers.** So, your comment adds no value or use, and serves only to litter the comment-space with noise. – Me

[**This is actually not true.**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97718/does-the-op-of-a-question-get-a-message-in-the-inbox-when-i-update-my-answer)

In fact, this [feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157248/could-we-have-a-way-to-notify-users-when-an-answer-is-edited) [has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127075/notify-when-someone-edits-an-answer-to-your-question) [been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134015/an-answer-to-ones-question-is-edited-why-doesnt-one-get-an-inbox-message) [requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64692/notify-question-op-and-those-who-marked-it-a-favourite-if-an-answer-has-been-m) [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97740/optional-notification-on-an-edit-to-an-answer) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188163/can-we-have-a-notification-when-the-answer-to-any-of-my-question-got-edited), but it has been declined and/or deferred.  In an answer to one of these requests, Jeff Atwood explicitly [recommended using comments to notify the question asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97740/optional-notification-on-an-edit-to-an-answer/97756#97756) of significant edits:

> "Post owners are always notified of comments on their posts.
>
> Thus, leaving a comment should suffice, if you feel your edit is so significant as to warrant notification."
>
> <sup>— Jeff Atwood ♦, answered Jul 7 '11 at 12:09</sup>

Comment: Really? I...was that always true? I seem to recall being notified of edits to answers to my own questions (albeit I can't remember quite how long ago that was).

Comment: Looking at the datestamps on those requests, it seems to have been this way at least since 2010.  (Ps. I just edited my answer; if you didn't get separately notified about that, it still works that way.)

Comment: @DavidThomas: I've been active on SO since August 2009 or thereabouts. I'm pretty sure in that time askers have never been notified of edits to answers, just the *addition* of an answer. "Check my answer" comments remain pointless, but "I've edited my answer to deal with your recent change to the question" or some such is okay.

Comment: Weird; in which case I have no idea as to quite why I was under that impression. Thanks for the correction, to both of you!

Comment: @DavidThomas - you do get notified if someone else edits an answer you wrote. That's not the same as the OP being notified about that edit, or one you make yourself. Maybe that's what you remember happening in the past?

Comment: I believe if those "look at my answer" spam comments come from newbie users **questions can be protected to avoid it**

Comment: @MarcoA. If they can comment, they have enough rep to get around the "protected" status

Comment: @lzkata You're right. It might be nice though to extend the protected status a step more than the comment one.

Comment: @Alex: I'm aware of that but, for some reason, my brain is insistent that it remembers something akin to: "An answer to your question was edited," clearly I'm remembering *wrong*, and presumably, somehow, I'm confusing two separate things. It still feels very weird to me, though, that **a:** I'm wrong and, **b:** the person posting the question *isn't* notified of edits (since edits usually improve questions which might better address the question that was asked).

Comment: @DavidThomas - yes, I agree it's strange (about the lack of notification, not necessarily about you being wrong - not enough information to have an opinion on that *8-) but there are lot of trivial and incremental edits that might make it too noisy. I guess Jeff's reference to 'significant' edits is, well, significant.

Comment: This answer should be updated with info about the follow feature.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the above mentioned [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26325035/2333214).

Scenario:

There is a discussion going on regarding a question.

UserOne (*That will be me*) , who is not part of the discussion - posts an answer sighting `how to do x`, which doesn't get any sort of attention from the OP.

Discussion goes on...

After 20 minutes or so, OP asks `how do i do x`  in the discussion. User one, posts a comment: *"See my answer below"*.

---

Now if you look at it -

There are 2 comments from userOne, the first one which he would have deleted manually once the OP notices it, second as a reply for your comments.

5 comments from you - 2 of them are regarding the question.

Plenty of them from the rest.

If anyone got into an argument regarding this, there might have been lot more of these.

---

I'm not quite sure whether you should be this worried regarding a single comment, because it was clearly not like one posts an answer and immediately comments *"See my answer! See my answer!"* all over the place.

Maybe that single comment will put an end to the whole ongoing discussion..? (**It did**, except for your comments), how about waiting till the discussion is over to see what happens to those comments..?

Now should userOne flag your comments as obsolete since they became obsolete..? :)

---

My suggestions are:

1. if the question is old and dealt with, flag the comments which are obsolete, not constructive etc for the respective reason.
2. If a discussion is active, and the comments are abusive or spam - flag it immediately.

   else, give it some time, see how it ends up... or if you're busy, move on - maybe those engaged in the discussion will remove the unwanted comments manually, or a future visitor will flag it for you (*Step 1*).

Comment: "*Now should userOne flag your comments as obsolete since they became obsolete..?*" - quite possibly, my comments are not intended to be exempt from criticism, and part of the purpose of posting here is to *invite that criticism* if it's justified.

Comment: Maybe you should have said something more along the lines: "That's already in my/the/poster's answer(s)." Makes it obvious you aren't just begging for attention.

Comment: OT note because you haven't listed a contact email in your profile: [this answer that you've deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34450694/1269037) was written by Google's tech lead for AMP developer advocacy.

Comment: @DanDascalescu That is not an **answer**, It's just a link, which should be a comment. I just voted to delete it as such, I did not delete it all by myself.

Comment: OK, can you then please check if that question is indeed a dupe, and help close it?

Answer (score 2):

Those comments are useless. As you pointed out, the OP is notified of new answers anyways. Commenting is just noise.

However, a comment of the form 'I've edited my answer' is more useful, because [edits don't receive notifications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274314/3187556).